# How to let fgets not stop reading at \n?

Tags: c, fgets

I want to read a fixed length of `char`s from a file. Therefore I use `fgets`, but `fgets` stops at `"\n"` reading.

How can I read the first N `char` even though one of them is a newline character?

I tried searching for other functions in the documentation but found none.

Comment: with the fread function.

Answer (score 4):

To read a fixed number of bytes from a stream, you should use `fread`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
             FILE * restrict stream);
```

`fread` attempts to read `nmemb` elements of `size` bytes each and returns the number of elements successfully read. It returns `0` at end of file.

Also make sure the file is opened in binary more with `"rb"` to prevent the translation of line ending sequences on legacy systems that may interfere with the byte counts.

Comment: Also stream should be opened in binary mode to not translate line endings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that your string is null character terminated you need to write your own function

```
char *freads(char *buff, size_t len, FILE *fi)
{
    size_t readBytes = fread(buff, 1, len - 1, fi);

    if(!readBytes) return NULL;
    buff[readBytes] = 0;
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest zero-terminating in all cases even when nothing is read and null is returned!

Comment: @SirJoBlack No, if returning NULL the code is not getting there.

Comment: If you set the buffer you avoid eventual use of incorrect data and obtain that in two cases the buffer will be empty, on the other hand is obvious that testing the NULL value returned by the function  the caller should know that the buffer is not valid because there're no more data in the read file. 

Anyway what you say is ok!